# array of object fill a new object array with specific matches

Tags: javascript

How can I have an object property from an array of objects (`inputArray`) added to another array (`output`).

```
var inputArray = [
 { subject: 'Maths', integervalue: '40', booleanvalue: null },
 { subject: 'Science', integervalue: '50', booleanvalue: null },
 { subject: 'Chemi', integervalue: '35', booleanvalue: null },
 { subject: 'Stats', integervalue: null, booleanvalue: true },
 { subject: 'Other', integervalue:  null, booleanvalue: false },
 { subject: 'History', integervalue: null, booleanvalue: true },
];
```

`output` should be added to when the `subject` property matches from each object.

If match is on `'Chemi'`, `output.suba` should be equal to the `integerValue` property of `inputArray` where the `subject` is `'Chemi'`.

Ergo, will be set to the value of

```
inputArray[2].integervalue.
```

If `integerValue` is null, then it should be set to the `booleanValue` property from `inputArray`.

So `output` would look like this:

```
var output = {
 suba: inputArray[n].integervalue,
 subb: inputArray[n].integervalue;
 subc: inputArray[n].integervalue;
 subd: inputArray[n].booleanvalue;
 sube: inputArray[n].booleanvalue;
 sudf: inputArray[n].booleanvalue;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please describe more what suba: value should be at the end ?

Comment: By the way, "null" is written lowercase in javascript.

Comment: now i see how is confusing people , sorry for that. @Usman Wali

Comment: Please update the question with the expected output based on your provided input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array#map` to generate an array of objects of your new string. Then using `Object.assign()` you can create a new object with all the key-value.

```js
var inputArray = [ { subject: 'Maths', integervalue: '40', booleanvalue: null }, { subject: 'Science', integervalue: '50', booleanvalue: null }, { subject: 'Chemi', integervalue: '35', booleanvalue: null }, { subject: 'Stats', integervalue: null, booleanvalue: true }, { subject: 'Other', integervalue: null, booleanvalue: false }, { subject: 'History', integervalue: null, booleanvalue: true }],
    output = Object.assign(...inputArray.map(({subject,integervalue, booleanvalue}) => ({[subject]:integervalue || booleanvalue})));
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
    var inputArray = [
     { subject: 'Maths', integervalue: '40', booleanvalue: null },
     { subject: 'Science', integervalue: '50', booleanvalue: null },
     { subject: 'Chemi', integervalue: '35', booleanvalue: null },
     { subject: 'Stats', integervalue: null, booleanvalue: true },
     { subject: 'Other', integervalue:  null, booleanvalue: false },
     { subject: 'History', integervalue: null, booleanvalue: true },
    ];
    
        
    var myOutput = inputArray.reduce( function(output, currentValue) {
          output[currentValue.subject] = currentValue.integervalue || currentValue.booleanvalue;
          return output
        }, {});

console.log(myOutput);
```

Comment: sorry missed that, but fixed

Answer (score 0):

Solution which uses number index not letter index, if you need letter index i could improve this.

```
const output = inputArray.reduce( ( _output, e, _index ) => {
  const query = `WHERE subject is = ${e.subject} set ${e.integervalue || e.booleanvalue}`

  _output[ `sub${_index}` ] = query;
  return _output;
}, {} )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hendry's solution can be modified to have letters index like this:

```
const output = inputArray.reduce( ( _output, e, _index ) => {
  const query = `WHERE subject is = ${e.subject} set ${e.integervalue || e.booleanvalue}`
  const charIndex = String.fromCharCode(97 + _index);

  _output[ `sub${charIndex }` ] = query;
  return _output;
}, {} )
```